# Multiple PC's VGA outputs mirroring on multiple monitors with switching capability

Tags: mirroring, vga

Let’s assume that we have a classroom that in the center of the room are some desks, and on each desk there is one Zero Client and monitor that students can use for their homework’s and education.

Around the room and on the walls, there are some mounted monitors (Like 6 or 7 monitors).

The question is how we can:

1. Mirror one of the zero clients VGA output on all mounted monitors.
2. Or switch to one-to-one connection, I mean one zero client mirror its output on one of the mounted monitors.

Is there any device or any solution to implement this, it must be convenient to use for someone like a teacher to switch between outputs.

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found it, something like 8x8 HDMI Matrix Switcher or 8x8 VGA Matrix Switcher can solve my problem.